# Select ALL columns from a table + sysdate

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

I need to select all the columns from a table and then the SYSDATE, but I got an error:

```
00923. 00000 -  "FROM keyword not found where expected"


select *, sysdate from HOTEL_PSD WHERE HOTEL_PSD_ID = 608316502;
```

Comment: When you want more columns, you have to put the table name/alias in front of the star, like `select HOTEL_PSD.*, sysdate from HOTEL_PSD...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oracle requires a table alias with `*`, when it is not the only column reference in the `SELECT`.

I strongly recommend giving all tables aliases that are abbreviations for the table name, so:

```
select hp.*, sysdate
from HOTEL_PSD hp
where hp.HOTEL_PSD_ID = 608316502;
```

Oracle is the only database that I regularly use that has this requirement.

Comment: One problem I encountered was trying to use SYSDATE in a complex select query within a case statement. Something to the effect of:
CASE WHEN EXPIRE_DATE < SYSDATE THEN 'EXPIRED' ELSE 'VALID' END

There are many tables I am joining on, and I kept getting the following error:
ORA-01792: maximum number of columns in a table or view is 1000

I solved this by adding the following to the FROM:
, (SELECT SYSDATE AS "TODAY_DATE" FROM DUAL) MY

Which makes the case statement:
CASE WHEN EXPIRE_DATE < MY.TODAY_DATE THEN 'EXPIRED' ELSE 'VALID' END